# android sqlite Select rows using List<String>

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to query musics based on genre. And each music has different genres being set. So inside my `List<Music> genre` I have the values `pop, rnb`. However I'm unable to get any data of rows with this. I only managed to get data using one String but not with `List<String>`. I dont get any values when I pass the `List<String> genre` on the `List<Music> musicList`. I also tried to debug the code and I'm getting null values. How can i get results using `List<String>` values?

Example
Music table

```
id | title     | genre    | artist
-----------------------------------
1  | MusicTest | pop, rnb | John
4  | Test      | rnb      | Jude

Genre
id genre
1 pop
2 rnb
3 rock

Genre Tags
id genre_id music_id
 1     1         1
 2     1         1
 3     3         4
```

Expected result should be

```
Music
Test
```

This is my search query method. I've updated the query

```
public List<Music> getMusic(List<String> genres) {
        List<Music> musicList= new ArrayList<>();
        int size = genre.size();
        Music music = new Music(); //getting null here

        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT a.title AS MusicTitle"
                    + ", GROUP_CONCAT(t.genre) AS Genre FROM music AS a"
                    + " LEFT JOIN genre_tags AS gt ON gt.id_music = a.music_id"
                    + " LEFT JOIN genre AS g ON g.genre_id = gt.id_genre"
                    + " WHERE g.genre LIKE '%" + genres + "%'"
                    + " GROUP BY a.music_id, a.title", null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    music.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                    musicList.add(music); //getting null here
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
        return musicList; //returns size = 0
    }
```

getting data from single genre

```
 public List<Music> getMusic(String genre) {
         List<Music> musicList= new ArrayList<>();
         sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Music music = new Music();

       Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT a.title AS MusicTitle"
                    + ", GROUP_CONCAT(t.genre) AS Genre FROM music AS a"
                    + " LEFT JOIN genre_tags AS gt ON gt.id_music = a.music_id"
                    + " LEFT JOIN genre AS g ON g.genre_id = gt.id_genre"
                    + " WHERE g.genre LIKE '%" + genre + "%'"
                    + " GROUP BY a.music_id, a.title", null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    music.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                    musicList.add(music);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
        return musicList;
    }
```

This is how I get the data

Toast it and I was able to get the values`pop, rnb`

```
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);
        List<String> genre= (List<String>)bundle.getSerializable("selectedGenres");
```

However when pass the data here on `musicList` I dont get any values

```
   DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Music> musicList= db.getMusic(genre);

    assert musicList!= null;
    String a = "";
    for(Music ms : musicList) {
        a = a + ms.getTitle() + "\n";
    }
    textView.setText(a);
```

Comment: Music music = new Music(); create this object outside of the cursor loop

Comment: @brahmyadigopula it's still not working

Comment: you need to use group concatenation refer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/combine-column-from-multiple-rows-into-one-row-in-sqlite and here too http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat

Comment: @brahmyadigopula Thanks. I used the one you recommended and updated the query however I'm still not getting any values.

Comment: but for your problem group concatenation is the only solution so keep try in that way

Comment: @brahmyadigopula I managed to get values only when using a String but not with List<String>.

Comment: `'Where 1=1 '` and add `' AND  g.genre LIKE '%" + genres(i) + "%''` for all list members.

Comment: @Serg It's still not working

Comment: Show  structure and example data of all 3 tables in query

Comment: @Serg updated the question

Comment: You have regular db structures for m-m relationship, build the sql on it, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having m-m tables as shown in edited question, you needn't `like`. Build sql as follows

```
-- test setup
CREATE TABLE Music (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `title` TEXT,
    `artist`    TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE genre (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `genre` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE GenreTags (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `genre_id`  INTEGER,
    `music_id`  INTEGER
);

insert into music(title,artist)
values ('MusicTest','John'), ('Test','Jude');

insert into genre(genre)
values ('pop'),('rnb'),('rock');

insert into genretags(music_id,genre_id)
values (1,1),(1,2),(2,3);

-- the query

select title
from music m 
where id in(
  select mg.music_id
  from GenreTags mg 
  join Genre g on g.id = mg.genre_id
  where  genre in (
   -- build this line from List<String> genres
     'pop','rnb' 
     )
  group by mg.music_id
  having count(*) = 2  -- genres.size()
 )
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm still unable to get any values

Comment: return musicList; It always return 0

Comment: Runs OK in DB Browser for SQLite. Check the string passed to `rawQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public List<Music> getMusic(List<Music> genres) {
    List<Music> musicList= new ArrayList<>();
    int size = genre.size();

    sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUSIC, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Music music = new Music();
                String title = music.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                if(soundex(genre.equals(title ))
                {
                  musicList.add(music);
                 }

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
    return musicList;
}


 public static String soundex(String s) {
    try {
        char[] x = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        char firstLetter = x[0];

        // convert letters to numeric code
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            switch (x[i]) {

                case 'B':
                case 'F':
                case 'P':
                case 'V':
                    x[i] = '1';
                    break;

                case 'C':
                case 'G':
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'Q':
                case 'S':
                case 'X':
                case 'Z':
                    x[i] = '2';
                    break;

                case 'D':
                case 'T':
                    x[i] = '3';
                    break;

                case 'L':
                    x[i] = '4';
                    break;

                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                    x[i] = '5';
                    break;

                case 'R':
                    x[i] = '6';
                    break;

                default:
                    x[i] = '0';
                    break;
            }
        }

        // remove duplicates
        String output = "" + firstLetter;
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++)
            if (x[i] != x[i - 1] && x[i] != '0')
                output += x[i];

        // pad with 0's or truncate
        output = output + "0000";
        return output.substring(0, 4);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info("Soundex Exception - " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return "";
}
```